# How to set a CSS value from an Attribute in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to set an element's background color from an attribute. At the current moment I am trying:

```
$( '[myAttr]' ).css( 'background-color', $( this ).attr( 'myAttr' ) );
```

but `$( this ).attr( 'myAttr' )` is returning undefined.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Post your html and script. `this` probably isn't referring to what you think it is referring to.

Comment: Provide the code snippet as it is yet not clear what this is referring.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `this` doesn't refer to the `[myAttr]` element because there is no scope.

You could pass an anonymous function (so that you have access to `this`), and return the attribute value:

```
$('[myAttr]').css('background-color', function () {
  return $(this).attr('myAttr');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not relevant outside of a callback. Do something like this...

```
$('[myAttr]']).each(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', $(this).attr('myAttr'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` probably isn't referring the element. Try like below.

```
var elm = $('[myAttr]');
elm.css('background-color', elm.attr('myAttr'));
```